# ammo.js btBvhTriangleMeshShape colider not working

Tags: javascript, ammo.js

I'm trying to make a static rigid body collider from the vertex data of a gltf model and I cant get it to work. I only use this mesh collider for the floor, but all the other objects just glitch for a second and then fall trough. If I change the btBvhTriangleMeshShape to a btBoxShape it works just fine, but I would like to have the option to add non box elements to my game map. Is there maybe a better alternative to the btBvhTriangleMeshShape?

```
const indexOffset =
    model.mesh.primitives[0].indices.bufferView.byteOffset / 2;
const indexLength =
    model.mesh.primitives[0].indices.bufferView.byteLength / 2;
const index = new Uint16Array(
    model.mesh.primitives[0].indices.bufferView.buffer
);

const position = new Float32Array(
    model.mesh.primitives[0].attributes.POSITION.bufferView.buffer
);

const positionOffset =
    model.mesh.primitives[0].attributes.POSITION.bufferView
    .byteOffset / 4;
const positionLength =
    model.mesh.primitives[0].attributes.POSITION.bufferView
    .byteLength / 4;

this.trimesh = new Ammo.btTriangleMesh();
for (let i = 0; i < indexLength; i += 3) {
    let j = 0;
    const vertexes = [];
    while (j < 3) {
        let ind = index[indexOffset + i + j] * 3;
        vertexes.push(
            Ammo.btVector3(
                position[positionOffset + ind],
                position[positionOffset + ind + 1],
                position[positionOffset + ind + 2]
            )
        );
        j++;
    }
    this.trimesh.addTriangle(vertexes[0], vertexes[1], vertexes[2]);
}

this.geometry = new Ammo.btBvhTriangleMeshShape(
    this.trimesh,
    true
);

this.transform = new Ammo.btTransform();
this.transform.setIdentity();
this.transform.setOrigin(
    new Ammo.btVector3(
        this.model.translation[0],
        this.model.translation[1],
        this.model.translation[2]
    )
);

this.transform.setRotation(
    new Ammo.btQuaternion(
        this.model.rotation[0],
        this.model.rotation[1],
        this.model.rotation[2],
        this.model.rotation[3]
    )
);

this.motionState = new Ammo.btDefaultMotionState(this.transform);
this.localInertia = new Ammo.btVector3(0, 0, 0);
this.geometry.calculateLocalInertia(this.mass, this.localInertia);
this.rbInfo = new Ammo.btRigidBodyConstructionInfo(
    this.mass,
    this.motionState,
    this.geometry,
    this.localInertia
);
this.body = new Ammo.btRigidBody(this.rbInfo);
this.body.setFriction(this.friction);

physicsWorld.addRigidBody(this.body);
```

Comment: I saw this related bug: https://github.com/kripken/ammo.js/issues/5

The problem was simply a missing 'new' keyword in the JavaScript.

Perhaps you need to add this when creating your vertices:
        vertexes.push( Ammo.btVector3(...))

Should be:
        vertexes.push(new Ammo.btVector3( ... ))